Unable to import the application from datastore into appvolume manager
We are using automation to complete the capturing process using app volumes tools.
We are unable to import the application from our datastore into App volume manager by using the API
https://$AppVolServer/app_volumes/app_products/import
We dont see any error in the logs. Any ideas?
